# Data Structre of Stack in C

Tags: c, data-structures, stack

I am new to structure and trying to implement a stack together with manipulation of pushing data in stack and print them. However, I came into some problems, could you help me with that please?

I used compiler provided by tutorialpoints in which the code is compiled successfully but the output contains a segmentation error which I assume exists in 'PushNode' or 'PrintStackData'.

And when I output the number of node in the stack(using Counter), the number is one more than the correct one, say I input 5 data, but it prints out 6.

Thank you very much!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



//Define data node
typedef struct Node{
    int data; //Data of data node in Stack
    struct Node *Next;  // Pointer pointing to next data node or null
}NODE;

//Define head node for stack
typedef struct StackHead{
    int Counter;
    NODE *Top;
}STACKHEAD;

// function to create a blank stack
void CreateStack(STACKHEAD *Head){      
    Head= (STACKHEAD*)malloc(sizeof(STACKHEAD));
    Head->Counter=0;
    Head->Top = NULL;   
};

//Function to push a data node in stack
void PushNode(STACKHEAD *Head){

    NODE *pNew=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE)); //Must allocate memory to initialise it otherwise segmentation error.
    printf("Enter value for new data Node: ");
    scanf("%d",&(pNew->data));  //Assign input to data of new node

    if(Head->Top==NULL){
        pNew->Next=NULL;
    }
    else{
        pNew->Next=Head->Top;
    }
    Head->Top=pNew;
    Head->Counter++;
};

//Function to print out each data node in the Stack
void PrintStackData(STACKHEAD *Head){

    STACKHEAD *Position=(STACKHEAD*)malloc(sizeof(STACKHEAD));

    //Position->Top=Head->Top;
    Position = Head;

    printf("The data in the Stack is: ");
     while(Position->Top!=NULL){
         printf("%d, ",Position->Top->data);
         Position->Top= Position->Top->Next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int numOfData; // Number of data that users want to insert into the stack
    STACKHEAD *Head; //Declare and initialise a new Stack Head
    CreateStack(Head); // Initialise the Stack

    printf("How many data do you want to insert to the Stack?");
    scanf("%d", &numOfData);

    for(int i=0;i<numOfData;i++){
        PushNode(Head);
    }
    printf("The data value of the top Node is %d\n", Head->Top->data);

    PrintStackData(Head);   //print out each data node in Stack using function.

    printf("\nThe number of data in the Stack is: %d\t", Head->Counter); 

    printf("\nThe data value of the top Node is %d\t", Head->Top->data);
    getchar();

}
```

Comment: Search for and read about *emulating pass by reference in c*. Or how to return values from functions.

Comment: "Please debug my code" questions are off topic/not allowed.

Comment: You never initialized `Head`. Assigning to `Head` inside the `CreateStack` function doesn't modify the caller's variable.

Comment: `CreateStack` should **return** the allocated structure, not take it as an argument.

Comment: By the way, your `PrintStackData` function contains a memory leak. *And* a very bad logical error where you rewrite your stack (and cause even more memory leaks).

Comment: I'm personally not that fond of the `PushNode` function either, with it reading input from the user instead of having the data passed as an argument., That's just my personal view though.

Comment: Thank you Joachim, Tyler and Barmar =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call CreateStack, the pointer is passed by value. The pointer that is returned by the call to malloc in your function is never assigned to the STACKHEAD.

Try writing a CreateStack function that returns a pointer to the stack that gets created. It should not take any arguments.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I will try it out. And also thanks for everyone, you guys make me improved :)